# sed inline with other file content

Tags: awk, sed

With GNU `sed` I'm trying to replace inline a single line in a file *(which can have more than one occurrence in it)* while keeping the whitespace behind it.

The files references will contain paths.

Here's an example of the original file (`fileA`):

```
    key
    key2
    key3
    keyword-here: 
    key5
    key6
    keyword-here:
    key7
```

Here is the content of the file *(`fileB`)* that holds the content that I'd like to use:

```
keyword-here: value1 value2 value3
```

The desired output:

```
    key
    key2
    key3
    keyword-here: value1 value2 value3 
    key5
    key6
    keyword-here: value1 value2 value3
    key7
```

I've been trying to use the following, but it fails to keep the spaces behind the matching keyword:

```
sed -e "/keyword-here:/r fileB" -e "/keyword-here:/d" fileA > fileOutput
```

Ideally I'd also be able to make the change directly in the file (`fileA`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for any strings in fileB since it's using literal string replacement and doesn't require you to hard-code the keyword since it's already present in fileB:

```
gawk -i inplace -F':' '
    NR==FNR { kw=$1; new=$0 }
    NR>FNR && s=index($0,kw FS) { $0=substr($0,1,s-1) new }
1' fileB fileA
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Not having the search keyword is a really awesome idea. TY!

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU [awk](/questions/tagged/awk): (`-i inplace` switch, replace *in place* like `sed -i`)

```
gawk -i inplace '
    NR==FNR{v=$0;print;next}
    {print (/keyword-here:/) ? gensub(/keyword-here:/, v, "g") : $0}
' fileB fileA
```

```
    key
    key2
    key3
    keyword-here: value1 value2 value3 
    key5
    key6
    keyword-here: value1 value2 value3
    key7
```

Comment: It outputs the correct substitution. Can it be made to replace inline instead?

Comment: Added inline remplacement

Comment: That will empty `fileB` since it's not printing while reading it and you're using `inplace` and you're setting `v` while reading fileB but never using it while reading fileA amd while reading fileA you're setting `o` to 1 or 0 based on whether or not `keyword-here:` exists on the line and then printing that 1 or 0 when you don't need to save the value in `o` and you should instead print `v` after saving/using the indentation from $0.

Answer (score 1):

Using *GNU `sed`* and `bash`:

```
sed 's/keyword-here:.*/'"$(<"fileB")"'/' "fileA"
```

Comment: forgot to mention the file is mentioned with a path. because of that i'm getting unkown option to s. I'll update my original question to mention the path requirement. any chance it can be changed to be compatible with slashes present in the path that is given to fileB?

Comment: @t988GF If `fileB` is actually `/foo/bar/fileB` that won't cause an error with this code. If the file's contents *include* a slash, now... (See my answer for an approach that doesn't have a problem with that scenario).

Comment: You'd also want to drop the `.*` from the RE or it'll eat the trailing space.

Comment: @t988GF Just add quotes -- see revised code, which should be compatible with 'file A' and 'file B' (spaces in the filenames, *etc*).

Comment: Still get sed: -e expression #1, char 48: unknown option to `s'. I'm trying with files with a path, as: /root/folder/fileA

Comment: @t988GF, Please post the output of `echo "/path/to/whatever/fileA" | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X "'` -- but with the actual file name and path.

Answer (score 0):

Put the contents of fileB into a variable, and use the substitute command to replace the part of the line starting with the keyword.

```
new=$(cat fileB)
sed "s/keyword-here:.*/$new/" fileA > fileOutput
```

Comment: Same issues as the other `sed` answer: The RE will remove trailing spaces, and if the file contains a slash, it'll cause errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of using `ed` instead of `sed` for in-place editing of files - it's what it was designed from the beginning to do, and doesn't have some of the portability problems of the non-standard `sed -i`. It only accepts commands from standard input, so the easy way to use it in a script is with piping `printf` output to it for simple cases, or heredocs for more complicated ones like this.

This series of `ed` commands finds every line containing `keyword-here:` and then for each one: Splits it up into three lines, with everything before the keyword, a dummy line, and everything after (Like any trailing whitespace). It then deletes the dummy line and replaces it with the contents of `fileB`, and joins the before line, new line(s), and after line all into one. Finally it saves the file.

```
ed -s fileA <<'EOF'
g/keyword-here:/s/keyword-here:/\
dummy\
/\
-2 ka\
-1 d\
-1 r fileB\
'a,+1 j
w
q
EOF
```

After running this command, `fileA` looks like

```
    key
    key2
    key3
    keyword-here: value1 value2 value3_
    key5
    key6
    keyword-here: value1 value2 value3
    key7
```

(I replaced the trailing space character with an underscore to make it more visible for demonstration and testing purposes)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '1{x;s/^/cat file2/e;x};G;s/^(\s*)([^:]*:).*\n\2/\1\2/;P;d' file1
```

Copy file2 into the hold space.

Append file2 to each line of file1.

Match on keyword and remove everything from the original keyword to the match and only print the what is on the matching line from file2. Thus the original white space at the front of the line is preserved and all lines not matched are printed as is.

N.B. This also allows for other matching keywords in file2.